# Windows 7 icons shuffling

Tags: windows-7, icons

I have a client's computer that seems to have issues with icons that shuffle around. I've already tried to align them to a grid and turn off "auto arrange". It seems like that doesn't fix the issue. I'm wondering if there are any issues that could arise from the video drivers. In this case, they are Intel. Possibly, could there be any chance that icons get shuffled around during power save mode? I should also note that the screen resolution is fixed and does not change. Anyone have any troubleshooting ideas?

Comment: Do they ever remote into their box?

Comment: @Peter Maxwell: I don't believe so, but can you explain how that affects the icons?

Comment: Connecting via remote desktop will temporarily change the resolution to that of the client computer unless specifically configured otherwise. This shuffles the icons.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say @DarthAndroid. I've had the same problem from that before.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about that. I'll try it out.